# Google Apps Script Display Checkbox Based on Cell Value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a project of managing inventory to keep track of who borrowed what item.
The following is an image of how the platform looks like.
[image]

As you can see, starting from row 20, (In cell B20), a list of information will show for who borrowed/returned what and when they did it. I have formatted cell B20 with a filtering function so that it will display only relevant information for whatever name is typed in cell C7.

What I want to do is display checkboxes in Column A if and only if there is a value in Column B. An example will be the following image.
[image]

A very helpful person has managed to provide me with a Google Apps Script code of making the checkboxes appear. It looks like the following:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const sName = sheet.getName();
  sheet.getRange('A20:A').removeCheckboxes();

  if (sName === "Teacher's Input Form" && e.range.getRow() > 19) {
    const len = sheet.getRange('B20:B').getValues().filter(row => row[0] != '').length;
    if (e.range.getColumn() === 2) {
      const range = sheet.getRange(20,1,len,1);
      sheet.getRange('A20:A').removeCheckboxes();
      range.insertCheckboxes().uncheck();
    }
    if (e.range.getColumn() === 1 && e.range.getValues()[0][0] === true) {
      sheet.getRange('A20:A').uncheck();
      e.range.check();
    }
  }
}
```

This works very well except it doesn't when the values are filtered. An example will be this.
If I type any random thing into cell B20, a checkbox will appear in cell A20. However, if a value is added to B20 from a filtering function, the checkbox will not appear unless I type a random thing into cell B21. Only then, will a checkbox appear in cell A20 and A21.

What I want to achieve is have a checkbox appear in Column A if and only if there is a data in Column B, which data in Column B will be added using the filtering function for whatever name is typed in cell C7.

Anybody willing to help?

I have made a sample spreadsheet to help you visualize my problem.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qC3rbaG9wg2aod80Y5SqdXQGpU4rjNJoIqHmBtpoSrQ/edit?usp=sharing

Try inputting Bob or Ryan in cell H3. Filtered data will appear in B2:E5. You will notice that checkbox does not appear in Column A.

Afterwards try inputting any value in the last line after the filtered list. For "Bob" in instance, type anything in cell B6. You will notice that the checkboxes will now appear.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Well, I'm the very helpful person provided this piece of script.

Comment: The 1st condition check ```if (sName === 'Teacher's Input Form' && e.range.getRow() > 19) ``` means when sheet name is equal to 'Teacher's Input Form', and the edited cell has a Row number bigger than 19, only than the function will be run.

Comment: The senond condition check ```if (e.range.getColumn() === 2)``` means it runs only when the edited column is column C, since ```range.insertCheckboxes().uncheck();``` is placed inside this condition, therefor in theory, ```Checkboxes``` will only be insert to the ```range``` when any cell of Column C and have a row number higher than 19 is being edited.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help and reply. But I don't follow you now at the moment. I understand what happens with the 1st condition. Got that covered. Next.
For the second condition, ```if (e.range.getColumn() === 2)``` why does this suddenly indicate Column C? I'm trying to display checkbox based on Column B.

Comment: Sorry, e.range.getColumn() === 2 means Column = B, massed up with the index thing after solving to many arrays issues.

Comment: Ohhh.. ok. Got it. But still unable to solve the problem. I use the filter function and data pops up into row number higher than 19. But I can't get the checkboxes to appear unless I force add another row of random data. You will get what I mean in this spreadsheet example. 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qC3rbaG9wg2aod80Y5SqdXQGpU4rjNJoIqHmBtpoSrQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: the reason why it is not working, is because IN-APP functions in spreadsheet (e.g. =SUM(), =MAX(), or in your case =FILTER()), any of the built-in functions do not 'edit' your sheet values. 'onEdit trigger' needs you to 'input' something into the sheet, which none of the built-in functions do.

Comment: you should change the onEdit trigger condition to monitor (in your test sheet) 'H3', and when 'H3' is edited, run the function that renew and insert checkboxes.

Comment: Ohhhh. That's something new. Thanks for the opinion. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const sName = sheet.getName();
  
  // Condition-1: sheet name === "Teacher's Input Form";
  if (sName === "Teacher's Input Form") {
    const len = sheet.getRange('B20:B').getValues().filter(row => row[0] != '').length;
    
    // Condition-2: edit range === C7;
    if (e.range.getColumn() === 3 && e.range.getRow() === 7) {
      const range = sheet.getRange(20,1,len,1);
      sheet.getRange('A20:A').removeCheckboxes();
      range.insertCheckboxes().uncheck();
    }
    
    // Condition-3: column of edit range === A, row of edit range > 19, value === true;
    if (e.range.getRow() > 19 && e.range.getColumn() === 1 && e.range.getValues()[0][0] === true) {
      sheet.getRange('A20:A').uncheck();
      e.range.check();
    }
  }
}
```